# Using Microsoft Dynamics CRM in custom application

Tags: .net, dynamics-crm, crm

I have an application, whose primary goal is not to do CRM. However I want to make it do CRM as well.

Now, instead of making my own CRM tool I was wondering if I could use Microsoft Dynamics CRM tool to handle the CRM part and let my application do its primary goal.

I was wondering if this is possible and how? Can anyone please guide me with few leads, links etc.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can very easily do so. There is an extensive web service API usable from both .NET and JavaScript, a versatile plugin system (which kind of takes the place of database triggers) and Windows Workflow Foundation integration.
We have occasionally built custom applications for customers that in their use are independent from the CRM system, but share the security/authentication and database functionality, so we didn't have to build that ourselves.

There is an [Implementation Guide](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=1ceb5e01-de9f-48c0-8ce2-51633ebf4714) and an [SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=82e632a7-faf9-41e0-8ec1-a2662aae9dfb&displaylang=en) with a lot of information, though it might not really be that easy to find a starting point for your specific application.